# How to add default gateway to subnet

Tags: networking

I used the following command

```
route del -net X.X.X.X gw 0.0.0.0
```

And want to add this gateway again.

But when I try to do add it I receive an error

```
route add -net X.X.X.X gw 0.0.0.0 // echo's SIOCADDRT: Invalid argument
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to add routes

```sh
route ADD <destination-address> MASK <mask> <gateway-address>
```

> Note: This is for windows operating system.